# Erro ao implantar projeto EJB com lambda usando o glassfish 4

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, glassfish, ejb, java-8

Tenho em meu projeto dois arquivos java

**Primeiro.java**

```
package br.com.bom;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class Primeiro
{
}
```

**Segundo.java**

```
package br.com.bom;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Stateless
public class Segundo
{
    public String getTxt()
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                "alfa", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot"));
        list.replaceAll(s -> s.toUpperCase());
        return list.toString();
    }
}
```

com a seguinte ordem das classes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando eu implanto este projeto desta maneira no servidor do glassfish 4
ocorre tudo perfeitamente bem, implanta corretamente e funciona

o detalhe/problema é quando o arquivo java que contem Lambda (java 8) no caso **Segundo.java** esta em primeiro da ordem neste projeto

desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ao implantar o projeto EJB no servidor

ocorre o seguinte erro no log

> Failed to scan for annotations: 52264
>
> Archive type of (dir muito longo)...\TesteImplantacaoLambda\build\classes was not recognized.

quando eu uso Lambda, tenho este tipo de problema, querendo ou não, isso não faz sentido, onde a ordem das classes dentro do projeto fazem com que ele implante ou não, alguém já passou por isso?

tenho todos recursos na ultima versão tanto o netbeans quanto o glassfish

Comment: Seu server está rodando no windows? Se sim, quantos caracteres tem em "dir muito longo"?

Comment: ambos, terá momentos em que será no windows e em outros no linux.
61 caracteres ao todo - 
o caminho completo: C:\Desenvolvimento\Java\VERSAO\TesteImplantacaoLambda\build\classes

Comment: "muito longo" foi um exagero na verdade

Answer (score 1):

Parece que é um bug no Glassfish: [GLASSFISH-21287](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21287)

Ao que tudo indica, o componente HK2 é o culpado: [HK2-136](https://java.net/jira/browse/HK2-136)